# Message Alert Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, alert

Is there a Jquery Mobile functionality that provides alert messages on page content and it disappears after a while? Like Growl for example.

Preferably it was not a plugin, but if there is no other choice could anyone give me one please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, when this was asked there wasn't really a way to do it "natively" - however, I did (recently) put together a quick plugin to use a mostly native way to do it, and, I hope, a somewhat sane method to go about adding quick information dialog popups (that time out).

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-AlertBox/ or https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-alertbox

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a Dialog? which you close automatically using javascript?

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options you can experiment with for Tooltip

[Under Development in JQM](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html)... not sure when and if it makes to the main release.

[JQMTooltip plugin](http://yupso.com/jqmTooltip/)
A plugin for popovers. You can use a timer to hide it for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for a while the same thing, but I've found nothing else than a 3 years old pending request: 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/499

If you are using PhoneGap as I suppose, you can use this simple PhoneGap plugin:

https://github.com/Pyo25/Phonegap-Toast-plugin